# How to add or remove a git tag by using GUI on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-gui, git-tag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use tags for versioning in git gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158598/how-to-use-tags-for-versioning-in-git-gui)

I install Git-1.7.11-preview20120710 and my OS is Windows.

Adding or removing git tags from command line is easy:

Adding a tag:

```
git tag -a v1.4 -m 'my version 1.4'
```

Removing a tag:

```
git tag -d v1.4
```

But how to add or remove tags by using GUI?

Note: I don't install any thing other than Git-1.7.11-preview20120710. Git-1.7.11-preview20120710 has built-in GUI.

Comment: Did you check out the `Create tag` and `Delete tag` menu options under the commands menu? Sorry this is for the git extensions install those - lots of extra feature - http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are other ways, but a way of doing this is by going to Repository > View log/history ...

On the log window, you can rightclick on any commit and there you will have to option to create and delete tags, along with many other options.

I recommend you to take a look at https://tortoisegit.org/. Its the best gui client for git on Windows (although I have to mention [GitHub For Windows](http://windows.github.com/), that seems awesome, but I haven't had any experience with it, yet) and has many features on the context menu of the repository (right-click on the repository folder). It also has many translations, so if your home language isn't English, you can install a language pack of your preference.

Comment: I don't seem to find an option to actually delete a tag in this manner :/