# How do I use git bash to tag a repository that I cloned in Git Desktop?

Tags: git, bash, github

I have used GitHub Desktop to clone a Git repository branch. I need to use annotated tags on the current commit in that branch. The most relevant documentation I can find is that at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging which uses examples in Git Bash. I need to understand several things:

1. How to set the current scope of Git Bash to the repository and branch I want to tag.
2. If possible, find out how to tag code from GitHub Desktop OR the Git GUI

The example I am trying to emulate is this
$ git tag -a v1.4 -m "my version 1.4"
but how do I select a repo and branch?

Comment: move between directories with `cd`?

Answer (score 1):

> How to set the current scope of Git Bash to the repository and branch I want to tag.

If you are asking how to use particular repo in git bash out of multiple repos you are working, then either

- you can navigate to the directory where you have cloned the repo
  (where .git folder is present) and open a new git bash over there.

Or

- navigate to the directory using command cd in git bash.

Then you can do git checkout .

> If possible, find out how to tag code from GitHub Desktop OR the Git GUI

I haven't used git GUI much.
Check this answer : [How to use tags for versioning in git gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158598/how-to-use-tags-for-versioning-in-git-gui)

You'll need to run gitk from git gui. 
Go to tools -> Add -> Add gitk as command.
Now Go to tools -> gitk

This will pop-up a window showing all git commits. 
Right Click -> create tag -> enter required details and create.

Have you checked tortoise git?I find it easy to work with.